# What will happen if i will terminate the update in between (from the terminal)

Tags: installation, updates, error-handling, partial-upgrade, usability

so i use computer for unknown time. sometimes i use it for more than 3 hr. and sometimes lesss than half hour. what will happen if i will stop the update from the terminal when the packages are being 
Q1- Downloaded?
Q2- Installed?

Comment: OP If you want to anything else , Just ask. we will do our best,:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the first case ("Q1") **you will be able to install only the downloaded packets with satisfied dependencies** and the package manager will ask to download any unsatisfied dependency.
2. In the second case ("Q2") **you will be able to use any installed packet but the performance and the functionality is not guaranteed**, since there can be unsatisfied dependencies and un-configured/mis-configured files. If you use a GUI it will **not** be updated with the latest links to any new software.
   In any case a good packet manager like *es*. `aptitude` will be able to signal and fix any problem. If you can, **never interrupt the installation of system packages**/files. ***NEVER*** interrupt the installation of a kernel.
   Remember that Linux can stay active for years without any software problem.
   Good afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

Q1 Ans :

while you are downloading the package updates from the terminal , If you interrupted with a restart/shutdown then

- previously downloaded packages will be save and you wont lost the downloaded files.
- you can resume the process with `sudo apt-get upgrade` again.

Q2 Ans :

This is completely prohibited and not recommended action. The consequences will be as

- your system may lost stability.
- your Ubuntu package architecture may have broken.
- In some cases you wont even able to have a normal start.

completely not recommended action.